# Route multiple domains to existing AWS resource

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a website that is hosted on AWS. I bought a new domain this AM and set up a new hosted zone for it in the AWS console. Then I created a new CNAME record to route it to my first domain. I thought this was the way to do it; am I wrong? Isn't there a simple way to point this new domain to my existing AWS resource?

Thanks for any helpful tips.

Comment: That method is perfectly fine. Or, give the other domains an equivalent configuration to the existing domain, so they point directly to the resource without going via a CNAME. Does it work? What "resource" are you pointing to -- EC2 instance, Load Balancer, API Gateway, etc?

Comment: Originally, I pointed the new domain to the same name servers that my original domain has but that didn't work. So now I point it to the new name servers from the new hosted zone and create a new record set with an A record and they point to my ELB enviro. The only problem is that I now need the "www" prefix for the new site in order for it to work -- and i don't need it for the original site. I'm using 2 certificates.

Comment: You should put that information into your question, since it seems to be relevant.